# Monitoring Google Test unit testing using Coverage Validator

Tags: unit-testing, frameworks, monitoring, code-coverage, googletest

I have just recently started carrying out unit testing for my software written in Visual Studio 2005 using *Google Test Framework*. Alongside, I have come across this tool to carry out code coverage known as:  [Coverage Validator](http://www.softwareverify.com/cpp-coverage.php). I am intending to monitor my unit tests using this Coverage Validator software but looks like it does not support Google Test Framework yet. It can carry out the monitoring using CPP unit but I was unable to find any documentation or way to do the same via Google Test. Is there a way through which I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Coverage Validator, but in general I don't see a reason why ANY coverage tool for CPP would need to officially 'support' ANY decent unit-test framework- it should just work...